# How does spark read and write data from Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

When I use spark-shell to excute `spark-sql` to query tables form Hive, how does spark read and write data from Hive? 
Is it via `JDBC` or something else？

Answer (score 0):

If you will check the `spark` [sourcecode](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala) . `Spark` doesn't use `jdbc`connection to `hive`. it uses `Hivemetastore` .

```
def newSession(): SparkSession = {
new SparkSession(sparkContext, Some(sharedState), parentSessionState = None, extensions)}
```

*Other than the `SparkContext`, all shared state is initialized lazily.*
*This method will force the initialization of the shared state to ensure that* parent and child sessions are set up with the same shared state. If the 
underlying catalog implementation is Hive, this will initialize the metastore,which may take some time

**comment source SparkSession.scala**